# How to get this prompt in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image: It's this image.]

I saw this prompt in a tutorial video on YouTube. I tried searching for relevant content in China, but unfortunately, I didn't find any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it is with the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + ;`.
In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts, then search for the command `Quick Fix...`. It is the shortcut that you are looking for.
Alternatively, you can simply click on the light bulb shown at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

These are called assists. To quote from the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/vs-code#assists--quick-fixes)

> Assists are code changes related to a certain code identifier. A
> number of these are available when the cursor is placed on a Flutter
> widget identifier, as indicated by the yellow lightbulb icon. To
> invoke the assist, click the lightbulb as shown in the following
> screenshot:
>
> [image: Code assists]
>
> You can also press Ctrl / Cmd + .